# Show multiple steps per image in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is it possible to view the images for all steps in the Image viewer of tensorboard?
Only the images corresponding to the last step are shown in the Images tab, though they are accessible changing the index of the the url of the image:

(Changing the 0 for the required step in the url: localhost:6006/data/individualImage?index=**0**&tag=777_mask_output_output_1%2Fimage%2F0&run=tensorboard_logs&ts=1487721119.455751)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, an additional slider was added at TensorFlow v. 1.1.0:

- [image]

Comment: Nice! That was what I was thinking about, because it seemed that the images where stored for all epochs, though only one was displayed.